# Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: хостинг, http-status-code-404

Впервые заливаю на бесплатный хостинг (Beget) сайт, собранный gulp'ом. Заливаю папку build, содержимое ее на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю это в папку public_html.

Но возникает ошибка 404: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуглила проблему, многие писали, что возникает она из-за отсутствия файла .htaccess, я его добавила, со следующим содержимым:

```
AddDefaultCharset UFT-8
ErrorDocument 404/404.php
```

В чем может быть проблема? Очистка кэша, истории браузера не помогают. На локальном хосте все работает, ошибка возникает только на хостинге.